# how to press Ctrl + ] in Selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have the ff.code which opens a chrome browser and press "F12" to open chrome dev tools, I've been searching in google on how to press Ctrl+] but unfortunately did not find any article/info about it. Has anyone here made this stuff? thanks!

```
    IWebDriver wdriver = new ChromeDriver();

        wdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.samplewebapp.com");
        wdriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        Actions action = new Actions(wdriver);
        action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F12).Perform();
```

Comment: `SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "]")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "]").Build().Perform();
```

or

```
yourWebElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "]");
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do a simlar thing, but with Control N (to open up a new browser window). Neither of these techniques worked for me. I am using C# and ChromeDriver. It seems to be a problem specific to chromedriver. From the past hour or so trawling stackoverflow, I am yet to find an answer. The action.sendkeys looked promising tho :(